# optimize table error are coming #2006 - mysql server has gone away in phpmyadmin

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

optimize table error are coming #2006 - mysql server has gone away in phpmyadmin
[image: Error that are coming]

Comment: This URL may be valuable in your search for a way to avoid this message.  https://haydenjames.io/mysql-server-has-gone-away-error-solutions/